# References not getting listed when using Biblatex approach

Tags: biblatex, citing, miktex

I am a beginner when it comes to Latex. I am using MikTex TexWorks on Windows.
I have already seen [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148601/sorting-references-last-names-alphabetical-order) post

However it seems I am still missing something when it comes to Biblatex approach and that's what I am specifically interested in.

Here's my simple code .tex file

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{myref}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{first-last}

\begin{document}
This is a sample document. This is a sample document.
This is a sample document ~\cite{Ref1}.  This is a sample document. \\

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

and my myref.bib file in the same folder is

```
@Article{Ref1,
  author =   {First, Last},
  title =    {Sample Article},
  journal =  {Journal 1},
  year =     {2006}
}
```

For @Article I believe these are a must to be included.

In MikTex it runs without any errors and generates the PDF, but reference is missing.

This is the PDF output. I am wondering where am I making a mistake. I am a beginner and am learning by following other examples already available.

[image]

Comment: Did you run the normal cycle, `pdflatex -> biber -> pdflatex (twice)`?

Comment: I am not too sure how to do that. All I know is to run a Green colored Run button in TexWorks and if there are no errors, PDF is produced.

Comment: Look in preferences to see what it says under build.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, I finally figured it out. For some reasons, path(reference) for biber.exe was simply missing in the Preferences-->Typesetting. I manually added it and now it'w working fine.